# Recovering deleted ext4 partition and master boot record

Tags: partitioning

I accidentally formatted an entire removable disk using the GNOME disk utility. I assume this means that I deleted an ext4 partition, protected by LUKS encryption, that was on the disk and the master boot record, but I didn't choose any option that would overwrite the data. Currently all that shows up is a raw device, that has no partitioning and no partitions.

My question is, is there some way to recover the disk as it was the moment before I formatted it?

I am using Debian 8.7

Answer (score 2):

If you used "Format Disk…" from the gearburger menu, that basically just writes a new partition table. The actual filesystems should still be there assuming you selected "quick format" without overwriting any data.

**testdisk** should be able to find lost partitions and automatically re-add them.

(Though since most USB disks only have one, you could also try guessing at its start position with fdisk – sector 63 or 2048 are common starting points.)

Comment: The partition on the drive is encrypted with LUKS, will testdisk also be able to recover it? I should have probably mentioned that.

Comment: You should have probably mentioned that. But, although I'm not sure if testdisk can detect LUKS, it _does_ have a recognizable header anyway (unlike TrueCrypt), so it's worth a try. And if not, then just bruteforce through the ~2000 possible starting sector values until you find it...

Comment: I am able to find the LUKS header, but when I recover it all I see is a 2MB LUKS partition. The password works, but I get a message that says "requested offset is beyond real size of device" and I can't access my data. Is this just a matter of resizing the partition

Comment: Probably. LUKS doesn't keep track of the container size, so there's no way for a recovery tool to determine it. Just grow the partition to the largest possible size and it should work.